# Given: $f(n)=2n^2-3$ and $g(n)=3n+4$, find $k(n)=(fgg)(n)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given: $f(n)=2n^2-3$ and $g(n)=3n+4$, find $k(n)=(fgg)(n)$?

solution:
\begin{align*}
fgg(n) &= f(g(g(n)))\\
&= f(g(3n+4)))\\
&= f(3(3n + 4) + 4)\\
&= f(9n + 16)\\
&= 2(9n + 16)^2 - 3\\
&= 2(81n^2 + 288n + 256) - 3 \\
&= 162n^2 + 576n + 509
\end{align*}
Check: Try $n = 1$, $f(g(g(1)) = f(g(7)) = f(25) = 2(25)^2 - 3 = 1247$,
$162(1^2) + 576(1) + 509 = 1247$

The practice test multiple choice answers are...

A. $6n^3+8n^2-9n-12$

B. $n^4+4n^3+4n^2+16n$

C. $-6n^3+8n^2+9n-12$

D. $n^4+4n^3+4n^2+16n$

Which one is it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks to me as though you need to multiply functions (fgg), given the solutions. Here, you are doing function composition, which given your earlier problem, seems you denote as $f\circ g\circ g$.

Comment: what is the correct ? answer I guess I was working backwards. right?

Comment: Yes, you composed the functions correctly. I'm suggesting that in earlier problems you posted, the notation $(fgg)(x)$ denoted the multiplication of the given functions. That's the only way you're going to obtain one of the given answers.

Comment: I think you should double check the "solutions" you are comparing your answer to: They cannot be solutions to either the composition of $f\circ g\circ g$ nor to the product of functions $(f\cdot g\cdot g)(x)$, for the given $f(x), g(x)$

Comment: I also tried exchanging the definitions of $ \ f \ $ and $ \ g \ $ , just in case _that_ was written down incorrectly.  There isn't any evident interpretation that can produce a quartic term $ \ ( x^4 ) \ $ with a coefficient of _only_ 1 ...

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me as though you need to multiply functions $(f\cdot g \cdot g),$ given the solutions. Here, you are doing function composition, which given your earlier problem, seems you denote as $f\circ g\circ g$. Composing the functions, you did that correctly, no mistakes (I ran through it myself.) So solution to composing the functions is correct, but matches none of the answers you provide.

$$(f\circ g\circ g)(x) = 162n^2 + 576n + 509$$

---

So, given the notation used in earlier problems you posted to day, try to multiply $f(x)\cdot g(x)\cdot g(x)$

So, you want to expand the following:

$$(f\cdot g\cdot g)(x)=(2n^2 - 3)(3n+ 4)^2 = 18n^4 + 48n^3 + 5n^2 - 72n - 48$$

But again, the correct result is not a match to any of the given solutions you post.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check what @amWhy noted by using Maple. It is a fun.

```
 > f:=n-> 2n^2-3:
 > g:=n-> 3n+4:
 > s:=n->(g@g)(n):
 > simplify((f@s)(n));
                                 162n^2+576n+509
```

Comment: Nice confirmation! +